# Having troubles with list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okey, I'm currently writing Conway's Game of Life and I have reached a point that I don't know how to solve.

Edit here are the different lists I'm having trouble with:

```
   for repeticiones in range(0,5):
    nuevo_mapa = mapax
    print(mapax)
    if '@' in mapax:
        print('Jell')
    if mapax is mapa_juego:
        print('God')
    for y in range(0,10):
        for x in range(0,10):
            if mapa_juego[y][x] == '@':
                viva_muerta = True
            elif mapa_juego[y][x] == '0':
                viva_muerta = False
            for i in range(0,8):
                try:
                    if mapa_juego[y + check_listy[i]][x + check_listx[i]] == '@':
                        sum += 1
                except IndexError:
                    pass
            if viva_muerta == True and sum in [0,1]:
                    nuevo_mapa[y][x] = '0'
            elif viva_muerta == True and sum >= 4:
                    nuevo_mapa[y][x] = '0'
            elif viva_muerta == True and sum in [2,3]:
                    nuevo_mapa[y][x] = '@'
            elif viva_muerta == False and sum == 3:
                    nuevo_mapa[y][x] = '@'
            sum = 0
    mapa_juego = nuevo_mapa
    print('\n\n')
```

mapax is a list of lists full of 0.

I want to do this:

1. nuevo_mapa = mapax
2. nuevo_mapa is modified
3. mapa_juego = nuevo_mapa

And start over and over again.
But the problem comes here, after the first iteration mapax is no more a full list of 0.
The output is something like this(I want publish it all because it's so messy and to avoid confusions)

```
>>> [0,0,0,0,0,0,0] First print of mapax
>>> [0,0,@,0,0,0,0] Second print of mapax and I want to avoid this.
```

If you see anything in the code let me know, thanks.

Edit: here are the different lists I'm having trouble with:

```
    mapa_juego = [
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','@','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','@','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','@','@','@','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',]
]
mapax = [
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',]
]
```

2 Edit: Here is full code:

```
    mapa_juego = [
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','@','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','@','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','@','@','@','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',]
]
mapax = [
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',],
['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',]
]
viva_muerta = None
check_listy = [0,0,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1]
check_listx = [1,-1,0,0,1,1,-1,-1]
sum = 0
#Reglas

# Una célula muerta con exactamente 3 células vecinas vivas "nace" (es decir, al turno siguiente estará viva).
# Una célula viva con 2 ó 3 células vecinas vivas sigue viva, en otro caso muere o permanece muerta (por "soledad" o "superpoblación").
# Célula viva = True muerta = False
# for line in mapa_juego:
#     print(line)

for repeticiones in range(0,5):
    nuevo_mapa = mapax
    print(mapax)
    if '@' in mapax:
        print('Jell')
    if mapax is mapa_juego:
        print('God')
    for y in range(0,10):
        for x in range(0,10):
            if mapa_juego[y][x] == '@':
                viva_muerta = True
            elif mapa_juego[y][x] == '0':
                viva_muerta = False
            for i in range(0,8):
                try:
                    if mapa_juego[y + check_listy[i]][x + check_listx[i]] == '@':
                        sum += 1
                except IndexError:
                    pass
            if viva_muerta == True and sum in [0,1]:
                    nuevo_mapa[y][x] = '0'
            elif viva_muerta == True and sum >= 4:
                    nuevo_mapa[y][x] = '0'
            elif viva_muerta == True and sum in [2,3]:
                    nuevo_mapa[y][x] = '@'
            elif viva_muerta == False and sum == 3:
                    nuevo_mapa[y][x] = '@'
            sum = 0
    mapa_juego = nuevo_mapa
    print('\n\n')
```

Edit 3: Real output

```
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']



['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '@', '0', '@', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '@', '@', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '@', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
God



['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '@', '@', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '@', '0', '@', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '@', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
God



['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '@', '@', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '@', '0', '@', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '@', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
God



['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '@', '@', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '@', '0', '@', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '@', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
God
```

Comment: No idea, if i get something I'll come asap.

Comment: If mapax= np.zeros(100, dtype=np.int), what does mapa_juego contain before you invoke the function? Looks like you're not copying nuevo_mapa into mapa_juego, before the second 'if' conditional.

Comment: @Mokshyam I edited to let you see the lists.

Comment: @Trig Pls provide the def for check_listx and check_listy

Comment: @Mokshyam I published full code, not very long. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Trig: printing the whole list at the beginning will give you a different o/p. Did you mean print(mapax[repeticiones])?

Comment: @Mokshyam I edited.

Comment: @Trig If you print(viva_muerta, sum) before the nested if checking for both of them, you mostly get False and sum <=5; and True and sum in [2,3]. Given your conditionals, @ is substituted. Is this nested if complete or are you missing any more coditionals?

Comment: Should your new array be an entirely new array of arrays, not sharing any storage with the old array? So your problems are coming about because you are modifying the original board, not a copy?

Comment: Also, let me suggest maintaining a set of live cells, rather than an array of dead/alive states. Then you construct the new generation as a new set, and replace the old set with the new one. See the `life` example [here](https://github.com/ldo/glibcoro_examples).